# Connecting to two server from client in qt

Tags: qt, tcpclient, qthread, qtcpsocket

I need simultaneous persistent connection to two Servers from my Qt TCP client.

Do I need threads for this or there is another way.
Any Examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Multiple `QTcpSockets` to connect to multiple `QTcpServers` Simultaneously.
`QTcpSockets` Can Connect only single Server